# SelectedItem column name in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datalist called `mymenu` which is populated with data from database.

```
 <asp:DataList ID="dl_menu" runat="server">
 </asp:DataList>
```

In the codebehind I am able to find the value of selected item as `mymenu.SelectedValue` or the parent of selected item as `mymenu.SelectedItem.Parent.Text`.Is there a way to find the
column name of the selected item rather then its value.

For example when i do `mymenu.selectedvalue` I get value 3 of column ccID.What should i do if i want to get the value as ccID?

Answer (score 1):

Well the [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) of a DataList is actually the value of the `DataKeyField` for the selected `DataListItem`. So I imagine your DataList must look something like this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl_menu" runat="server" DataKeyField="ccID">
</asp:DataList>
```

If you want to get the string value of "ccID", just use the DataList's `DataKeyField` property.

```
string dkf = dl_menu.DataKeyField;
```

You can't actually find a single column name for a selected item in a DataList. The DataList could contain multiple columns and you are actually selecting the entire `DataListItem` (the row) when you select it.